# addViewer the method used with the class DriveApp always sends the email to the recipient. Can I disable the email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Code A and B do the same things but in case A when add a viewer, the command addViewer don't send the email to currentUser. Instead, in the case B when add a viewer the currentUser receive an email of file sharing.

```
//CASE A
var f = DocsList.getFolderById(folder.getId());  
f.addViewer(currentUser);

//CASE B
var f = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.getId());
f.addViewer(currentUser);
```

I would like to share wihouth automatic email because at the end of procedure I'll send a custom email (with the file inside folder link) if the procedure completed successfull, otherwaise I will delete the folder.
How can I do? DocList will soon be deprecated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you'll need to use the [Drive API permissions.insert method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) [notice it's not DriveApp] to silently insert a permission.

The [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) is exposed to Google Apps Script through the [Google Drive Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). To use it you'll need to [enable it for your project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

Once that's done your permission insert code might look like this:

```
/**
 * Insert a new permission without sending notification email.
 *
 * @param {String} fileId ID of the file to insert permission for.
 * @param {String} value User or group e-mail address, domain name or
 *                       {@code null} "default" type.
 * @param {String} type The value "user", "group", "domain" or "default".
 * @param {String} role The value "owner", "writer" or "reader".
 */
function insertSilentPermission(fileId, value, type, role) {
  var request = Drive.Permissions.insert({
    'value': value,
    'type': type,
    'role': role,
    'withLink': false
  },
  fileId,
  {
    'sendNotificationEmails': false
  });
}
```

I've edited this answer to include Laura's feedback below so it now works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

the method require "p" uppercase: Drive.Permissions.insert
But after this little thing, the function returns an error:

```
The numbers of arguments is invalid. Expected 2-3
```

I tried with this:

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
{
  'role': 'reader',
  'type': 'user',
  'value': 'username@test.it'
},
fileId,  
{
  'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
});
```

It works fine but only for FILE. For FOLDER (in fileId i put a folder ID) happens a strange thing:

Before run this code sharing Settings of folder are:

- Share only with specific persons
- person@example.com        can view
- admin@example.com         is owner

After running the code sharing Settings of folder become:

- anyone in example.com with the link can view      --> this is WRONG
- username@example.com      can view                --> this is OK
- person@example.com        can view
- admin@example.com         is owner

Answer (score -1):

If you are sharing a file with Google Scripts, the email notification will always go to the viewers and editors. The option to not send that email is only available if you share a file manually inside Google Drive.