# How to send a custom message when adding a viewer to Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm trying to add a viewer to a Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps Scripts, and, while doing so, also send a custom message like "Hi there! I'm sending this to you becase X, Y and Z".

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645226/addviewer-the-method-used-with-the-class-driveapp-always-sends-the-email-to-the) here on SO related to silencing the email when adding an Editor, but I couldn't sort out how to modify it so I can send a custom message.

What I'm trying:

```
Drive.Permissions.insert({'value': "my@email.com",
                        'type': "user",
                        'role': "reader",
                        'emailMessage': "Random text"
                        },
                       'mySpreadsheetKey');
}
```

I expected the "emailMessage" to work for that purpose, as stated in the [Drive API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert). But, considering the parameters, I can see that that one specifically is not included in the request body, but, rather, on the parameters list, so I'm not sure about what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as I was finishing my post, I figured it out. It turns out that, in the final section of the [Advanced Drive Service docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), it is not specified, but, apparently, the request parameters should be sent as a third parameter, instead of sent inside the request body. So, my code turned out to be:

```
Drive.Permissions.insert({'value': "my@email.com",
                        'type': "user",
                        'role': "reader"
                        },
                       'mySpreadsheetKey',
                       {'emailMessage': "Random text"});
```

I decided to leave the question so it could help others, given the fact that I couldn't find a similar post.