# Adding message to email when using addEditor()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

In Apps Script, I'm currently programmatically generating files, adding a user via `addEditor()` and sending them an email automatically.

What I'd like to do now is expand this to include a message. I think this corresponds with this box in green:

[image]

I've also found a similar question here, but have been unable to get it working: [How to send a custom message when adding a viewer to Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381544/how-to-send-a-custom-message-when-adding-a-viewer-to-google-spreadsheet-via-goog)

This is what I have so far:

```
  setPermission(documentId, email) {

    // Get the document to set permissions on
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);

    // Turn off sharing by editors
    file.setShareableByEditors(false);

    // Add the email to editors
    file.addEditor(email);

  }
```

If I try to do something like:

```
...
file.addEditor(email, {emailMessage: 'Test'});
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: The parameters (String,(class)) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.addEditor.
```

So I'm curious if:

1. Is this doable?
2. And what does the syntax need to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditoremailaddress), `file.addEditor()` has only one argument: an email address (or a [User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditoruser) object).  So an email message cannot be added via that method.

However, you can accomplish this using the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive).
First you'll need to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) the Advanced Drive Service.

Then use something like this ([reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert)):

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
    'role': 'writer,
    'type': 'user',
    'value': email // the email address you wish to share with
  },
  documentId, // id of the file you want to share
  {
    'sendNotificationEmails': 'true',
    'emailMessage': message // The message you want to send, as a plain text string
  });
```